# Rasberry Pi 4B: Wifi adapter is detected in lsusb but not shows up as wlan1 (mt7612u)

Tags: drivers, wireless, usb, 22.04

The USB connection is detected as shown in dmesg belows:

```
[ 1106.391415] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[ 1106.416995] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0e8d, idProduct=7612, bcdDevice= 1.00
[ 1106.417027] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
[ 1106.417041] usb 2-1: Product: Wireless 
[ 1106.417053] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: MediaTek Inc.
[ 1106.417064] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 000000000
```

However in iwconfig, it is not there:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11  Mode:Master  Tx-Power=31 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
```

Here is my `uname -a`: **Linux pi 5.15.0-1023-raspi #25-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Fri Jan 6 17:33:55 UTC 2023 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux**

FYI, It was working properly in 18.04 before I upgraded it to 22.04.

Edited:

`sudo modprobe mt76x2u && sudo dmesg | grep mt76`:

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module mt76x2u not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.0-1023-raspi
```

`sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) | grep Status`:

```
dpkg-query: package 'linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-1023-raspi' is not installed and no information is available
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files.
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe mt76x2u && sudo dmesg | grep mt76` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 I have added the result of that command.

Comment: Please reboot and then add: `sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) | grep Status`

Comment: @chili555 Done, it seems I need to install that extra modules?

Comment: Yes. Do you have any connectivity at all? Ethernet? Tethering??

Comment: @chili555 I have the Ethernet. I used `sudo apt-get install linux-modules-extra-raspi` and now in iwconfig it shows `wlx00c0cab0216d`. I will try to see if I can put that up to work.

Comment: @chili55 I used `sudo ln -s /dev/null /etc/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules` to fix the name to wlan1. I hope that that is okay to do? Besides that everthing works now. Thank you!

Comment: I am unsure about the rules question. If it is working as expected, that's all you need. Glad it's working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to @chili555 's help

To solve the problem, just use `sudo apt-get install linux-modules-extra-raspi` to install the modules that contain drivers for the wifi adapter.